# undefined method `sidekiq_options_hash' for Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedModel:Class

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I get this error sometimes:

```
undefined method `sidekiq_options_hash' for Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedModel:Class
```

It happens seemingly randomly in various parts of the code which usually don't have problems in other identical situations. I'm not able to reproduce it. Based on this, my suspicion is that it is some sort of concurrency issue. I don't have guesses beyond that.

I'm on JRuby 1.7.18, perhaps that is relevant.

Here's the beginning of an example backtrace:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sidekiq_options_hash' for Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedModel:Class
  File "/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb", line 80, in get_sidekiq_options
  File "/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb", line 84, in client_push
  File "/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/extensions/generic_proxy.rb", line 19, in method_missing
  File "/app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb", line 53, in update_foo
```

application_controller line 53 is:

```rb
current_user.delay.update_column(:foo, bar) # bar is an instance of Time
```

Comment: Are you on the latest JRuby?  I've never seen that problem.

Comment: Hmm, pretty current.  1.7.19 is out (http://jruby.org/2015/01/30/jruby-1-7-19.html) but I don't see any relevant fixes.  Can you include your application_controller code around line 53?

Comment: Added to the end of the question above

Comment: No idea.  Pro tip though: don't delay instance methods.  It's likely just as fast to execute that update_column synchronously.